# Legacy LAMP Stack on Docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, architecture, lamp

I want to preface this by saying this question is more about system design and is somewhat open-ended. There isn't anything, in particular, I need help with. But I would appreciate some guidance. I will provide a copy of my `docker-compose.yml` so it's easier to visualize what I'm working with.

I'm looking to dockerize an older LAMP stack application. This app is currently deployed in a CentOS 6.10 VM, running PHP 5.4, MySQL 5.7, and Apache 2.2.15.

I wonder how I might go about dockerizing while minimizing the number of modifications I have to make to the underlying codebase.

I was playing with aliasing deprecated functions and redefining them with an updated API, but, it's been quite the hassle. Here's an example:

```php
if (!function_exists('mysql_num_rows')) {
    function mysql_num_rows($result)
    {
        return mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }
}
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
version: "3.8"

x-common-variables: &common-variables
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  MYSQL_USER: ...
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: ...

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: local

services:
  mysql:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql_container
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    container_name: phpadmin_container
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
      PMA_HOST: mysql
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    ports:
      - 8080:81
    restart: always

  apache:
    container_name: apache_container
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    build: ./bootstrap
    environment:
      <<: *common-variables
    extra_hosts:
      - "app1.localhost.com:127.0.0.1" # This is configured in local hosts file
      - "app2.localhost.com:127.0.0.1"
    ports:
      - 443:443 # App requires SSL - using a self-signed cert locally
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./bootstrap/httpd.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
      - ./bootstrap/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./:/var/www
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
```

I'm using the php:7.4-apache image for the apache service (not shown here, it's in the `Dockerfile`).

As I was writing this question, I realized I could probably use a centos image and install the older versions of software required for the project. However, I'm still going to post because any insight would be helpful.

Let me know if there's any more info I can provide!

Answer (score 0):

you can do that, but you can use many docker LAMP stacks almost ready to use at your own localhost, or with some additionnal configuration related to the webapp you are developing :

- https://github.com/akospasztor/docker-lamp
- https://github.com/sprintcube/docker-compose-lamp

You can use official Docker images too, as you have done :

- https://hub.docker.com/_/php where you can get for example : `docker pull php:fpm-bullseye`

You can use ready to build webapps Docker images :

- using laravel : https://github.com/ucan-lab/docker-laravel
- using symfony : https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker

I think you have some things to discover here, have fun.